# Extract link and text if certain strings are found - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to run beautifulSoup to extract links and text from a website (I have permission)

I run the following code to get the links and the text:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
     if "career" in link.get("href"):
             print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)
```

Which give me the following output:

```
View Position

</a>
<a href='/career/business-analyst-within-human-capital-management/'>
Business analyst within human capital management
COPENHAGEN • We are looking for an ambitious student with an interest in HR 
who is passionate about working in the cross-field of people management, 
business and technology




View Position

</a>
<a href='/career/management-consultants-within-strategic-workforce-planning/'>
Management consultants within strategic workforce planning
COPENHAGEN • We are looking for consultants with profound experience from 
other consultancies




View Position

</a>
<a href='/career/management-consultants-within-supply-chain-strategy-
production-and-process-management/'>
Management consultants within supply chain strategy, production and process 
management
MALMÖ • We are looking for talented graduates who want a career in management 
consulting
```

Which is almost correct, however I ONLY want the positions to be returned if they have the name COPENHAGEN in the text (ie above the MALMO position should not have been returned).

The HTML Code for the site looks like this:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-9 columns top-lined">
                                    <a href="/career/management-consultants-within-supply-chain-management/" class="box-link">
                                    <h2 class="article__title--tiny" data-searchable-text="">Management consultants within supply chain management</h2>
                                    <p class="article__longDescription" data-searchable-text="">COPENHAGEN • We are looking for bright graduates with a passion for supply chain management and supply chain planning for our planning and execution excellence team.</p>
                                    <div class="styled-link styled-icon">
                                        <span class="icon icon-icon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="icon-text">View Position</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Whats wrong Palle Broe? Didn't the given answer satisfy your requirement? If so, accept that otherwise make a comment why it is not? People waste their time preparing an answer. So, don't ignore that. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - have added in the comment now. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you can just add another condition:

```
(...)
for link in links:
    if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
       print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)
```